# Calculating difference between two rows in Python / Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

In python, how can I reference previous row and calculate something against it?  Specifically, I am working with `dataframes` in `pandas` - I have a data frame full of stock price information that looks like this:

```
           Date   Close  Adj Close
251  2011-01-03  147.48     143.25
250  2011-01-04  147.64     143.41
249  2011-01-05  147.05     142.83
248  2011-01-06  148.66     144.40
247  2011-01-07  147.93     143.69
```

Here is how I created this dataframe:

```
import pandas

url = 'http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=IBM&a=00&b=1&c=2011&d=11&e=31&f=2011&g=d&ignore=.csv'
data = data = pandas.read_csv(url)

## now I sorted the data frame ascending by date 
data = data.sort(columns='Date')
```

Starting with row number 2, or in this case, I guess it's 250 (PS - is that the index?), I want to calculate the difference between 2011-01-03 and 2011-01-04, for every entry in this dataframe.  I believe the appropriate way is to write a function that takes the current row, then figures out the previous row, and calculates the difference between them, the use the `pandas` `apply` function to update the dataframe with the value.

Is that the right approach?  If so, should I be using the index to determine the difference?  (note - I'm still in python beginner mode, so index may not be the right term, nor even the correct way to implement this)

Comment: wouldn't be enough to just find the rows for the two dates and calculate the difference between them..?

Comment: @redShadow interesting thought.  I hadn't thought about it like that.  The only issue I see is how would you handle weekends?  There are 252 trading days, not 365.  If you try and go up 1 day, and it's a weekend, the function would fail.  Although, I guess you could put some error handling in the function...

Comment: No, wait.. what exactly are you trying to accomplish? Calculate, for each day, the difference with the previous one, for all the records in the dataset..?

Comment: @redShadow exactly.  Line by line, the difference from the previous day.  first row will be 0, so I would have to figure out some error handling, but...

Answer (score 129, accepted):

I think you want to do something like this:

```
In [26]: data
Out[26]: 
           Date   Close  Adj Close
251  2011-01-03  147.48     143.25
250  2011-01-04  147.64     143.41
249  2011-01-05  147.05     142.83
248  2011-01-06  148.66     144.40
247  2011-01-07  147.93     143.69

In [27]: data.set_index('Date').diff()
Out[27]: 
            Close  Adj Close
Date                        
2011-01-03    NaN        NaN
2011-01-04   0.16       0.16
2011-01-05  -0.59      -0.58
2011-01-06   1.61       1.57
2011-01-07  -0.73      -0.71
```

Comment: Great but how would you add this is as a new column in data?

Comment: @Chang She, what if I didnt want the difference but the actual value. i.e. instead of diff(1) is there something like value(1) or value(1:3).mean(). The second made up example would get the mean of the next, second and third value. That would be useful

Comment: .shift() in pandas gives you the values.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For those who want the n-day difference, it is worth mentioning that you can set the input parameter `periods` to n. Check the `pandas.DataFrame.diff` documentation for more details: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html .

Comment: Answering the followup question by greenafrica. You can combine the original data with the new difference data using pd.concat, as for example: `pd.concat([data,data[['Close', 'Adj Close']].diff().rename({'Close':'Close Diff', 'Adj Close':'Adj Close Diff'}, axis=1)], axis=1)`

Comment: If you want to save the difference in another column, you can:
`df['close_diff'] = df['Close'].diff()`

Answer (score 30):

To calculate difference of one column. Here is what you can do.

```
df=
      A      B
0     10     56
1     45     48
2     26     48
3     32     65
```

We want to compute row difference in A only and want to consider the rows which are less than 15.

```
df['A_dif'] = df['A'].diff()
df=
          A      B      A_dif
    0     10     56      Nan
    1     45     48      35
    2     26     48      19
    3     32     65      6
df = df[df['A_dif']<15]

df=
          A      B      A_dif
    0     10     56      Nan
    3     32     65      6
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know pandas, and I'm pretty sure it has something specific for this; however, I'll give you the pure-Python solution, that might be of some help even if you need to use pandas:

```
import csv
import urllib

# This basically retrieves the CSV files and loads it in a list, converting
# All numeric values to floats
url='http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=IBM&a=00&b=1&c=2011&d=11&e=31&f=2011&g=d&ignore=.csv'
reader = csv.reader(urllib.urlopen(url), delimiter=',')
# We sort the output list so the records are ordered by date
cleaned = sorted([[r[0]] + map(float, r[1:]) for r in list(reader)[1:]])

for i, row in enumerate(cleaned):  # enumerate() yields two-tuples: (<id>, <item>)
    # The try..except here is to skip the IndexError for line 0
    try:
        # This will calculate difference of each numeric field with the same field
        # in the row before this one
        print row[0], [(row[j] - cleaned[i-1][j]) for j in range(1, 7)]
    except IndexError:
        pass
```

Comment: Downvoting this because, in addition to reproducing what pandas do, it is done with nested for loops, which is slow in Python. Pandas will do it at the C level.

Comment: downvoting as original question has tag ```pandas``` which directly points to way author want to solve his problem

Comment: Sometimes you won't know you want something until it is presented to you :)

Comment: The header says in `Python / Pandas`. That was perhaps misleading as well, at least a reason to start the answer at all. In `Python pandas` or `pandas (Python)` would have been better.