# Difference between elements when reading from multiple files

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to get the difference between each element after reading multiple csv files. Each csv file has 13 rows and 128 columns. I am trying to get the column-wise difference

I read the files using

```
data = [pd.read_csv(f, index_col=None, header=None) for f in _temp]
```

I get a list of all samples.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13114512/calculating-difference-between-two-rows-in-python-pandas) I have to use `.diff()` to get the difference. Which goes something like this

```
data.diff()
```

This works but instead of getting the difference between each row in the same sample, I get the difference between each row of one sample to another sample.

Is there a way to separate this and let the difference happen within each sample?

**Edit**

Ok I am able to get the difference between the data elements by doing this

```
_local = pd.DataFrame(data)

_list = []
_a = _local.index

for _aa in _a:
    _list.append(_local[0][_aa].diff())

flow = pd.DataFrame(_list, index=_a)
```

I am creating too many DataFrames, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: could you give a minimum complete sample of what `data` looks like after you've read it in?

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE] example using three 3x3 dataframes.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to find the difference between adjacent columns of the dataframe. Say `column[1] - column[0]` elementwise and so on?

Comment: Yes exactly. But with multiple samples.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a relatively efficient way to read you dataframes one at a time and calculate their differences which are stored in a list `df_diff`.

```
df_diff = []
df_old = pd.read_csv(_temp[0], index_col=None)
for f in _temp[1:]:
    df = pd.read_csv(f, index_col=None)
    df_diff.append(df_old - df)
    df_old = df
```

Comment: OK.  What is the output of `df.shape`.  I first want to ensure that you are reading the files correctly.  It should be (13, 128).

Answer (score 1):

Since your code work you should real post on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

(PS. The leading "_" is not really pythonic. pls avoid. It makes your code harder to read. )

```
_local = pd.DataFrame(data)
_list  = [ _local[0][_aa].diff() for _aa in _local.index ]
flow   = pd.DataFrame(_list, index=_local.index )
```