# pandas dataframe best way to check timestamps

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with a lot of timestamps:

```
|     |         ti_ms |
|-----+---------------+
|   0 | 1551398400000 |
|   1 | 1551398700000 |
|   2 | 1551399000000 |
|   3 | 1551399300000 |
|   4 | 1551399600000 |
|   5 | 1551399900000 |
|   6 | 1551400200000 |
|   7 | 1551400500000 |
|   8 | 1551400800000 |
```

The interval is always 3000 miliseconds (5 minutes).
I want to check if there is a gap, that means if the interval sometimes is bigger than 3000 miliseconds.

I would solve it like this:

make a new column with the delta between two following rows like this:

```
df['delta'] = df['ti_ms'] - df['ti_ms'].shift(1)
```

Then check if there is a df['delta'] != 3000 (except for the first row) --> if No everything is ok.

This seems to me not elegant enough. Is there a better way to look for a gap in the timestamps ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculating difference between two rows in Python / Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13114512/calculating-difference-between-two-rows-in-python-pandas)

Answer (score 1):

`df.diff()` should do. axis = 0 for rows and axis = 1 for columns yo can define.
for more reference check [Pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html)