# Calculating difference between two rows, based on another column match condition, in Python / Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have seen questions like [calculate the difference between rows in DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13114512/) & i understand Pandas provides `df.diff()` API but my question context is slightly different. DataFrame will consist thousands of rows with volume data till that time of the day. `Name` column indicates name of instrument. Need to calculate diff between `Volume` column only for matching `Name` column.

Input DataFrame :

```
         Date    Name   Volume
1  2011-01-03     A       10
2  2011-01-03     B       20
3  2011-01-03     C       30
4  2011-01-03     A       40
5  2011-01-03     B       30
6  2011-01-03     C       100
7  2011-01-03     A       140
8  2011-01-03     B       50
9  2011-01-03     C       120
```

Output DataFrame :

```
         Date    Name   Volume  Volume Diff
1  2011-01-03     A       10        10
2  2011-01-03     B       20        20
3  2011-01-03     C       30        30
4  2011-01-03     A       40        30
5  2011-01-03     B       30        10
6  2011-01-03     C       100       70
7  2011-01-03     A       140      100
8  2011-01-03     B       50        20
9  2011-01-03     C       120       20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question is vague. What if there are multiple dates in a group?

However, with what you have given, group by name, subtract consecutive rows in Name. Some will return nulls, fill those nulls with values from `Volume`

```
   df['Volume Diff'] = df.groupby('Name')['Volume'].apply(lambda x: x.diff(1)).combine_first(df['Volume'])
```

Comment: i have given this dataset cause date will be same. Thanks for the solution, will try & update.

Comment: Please let me know if it works for you. if doesnt  let me know what the issue is and I will help.

Comment: it works perfectly, thanks a ton. BTW is there a simple way to convert float values in column to int. Above solution is giving me float values in `volume diff` column, hence the follow-up.